# Bypass installing updates on shut-down

Tags: windows, automatic-updates

So with the cold weather, we're experiencing rolling blackouts in industrial sectors to keep residential heaters going. Every two hours for 15 minutes, we go dead. The last couple times this happened, we had workstations running on about 30 seconds' worth of UPS power, that we were trying to shut down quickly but the workstations were insisting on getting updates.

I need a way to bypass this; when I have 30 seconds to get a computer shut down, I don't care if I have the latest recommended updates, I need it shut down NOW. Are there any tips, other than "just make sure you have all the latest updates installed already"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To force a immediate shutdown and bypass updates install, use command line

```
   shutdown /s
```

For a more permanent solution, use Group Policy Objects

```
  gpedit.msc
```

**Enable**, on [computer\administrative templates\windows components\windows update]

- Do not adjust default option to 'Install Update and Shut Down' in Shut Down Windows dialog box

Answer (score 0):

Possibly STOP the Automatic Updates service first. I bet that will do it.

Windows 7 friendly name is **Windows Update**

Windows XP friendly name is **Automatic Updates** (I think)

Service name on both (if you want to run a *net stop*: **wuauserv**